# Como armazenar informações de um SELECT em variaveis

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

Boa noite comunidade,eu tenho um programa de estoque que estou finalizando e quero fazer uma validação para ele sempre conferir se tem o bastante daquele produto antes de adicionar na venda. Para isso usei uma simples operação matemática,aonde uma variavel armazena o valor pedido,outra o valor que existe no banco de dados e então uma terceira variavel armazena a subtração delas e testa num if. Entretanto eu estou com dificuldade de armazenar o resultado do Select na variavel,existe algum comando para obter o valor de uma celula de tabela ou coisa do tipo? segue abaixo o código

***Código:***

```
private void btAddProd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataTable tabela = new DataTable();
    DALConexao cx = new DALConexao(DadosDaConexao.StringDeConexao);
    var cod = Convert.ToString(txtProCod.Text);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select pro_qtde from produto where pro_cod like '%" + cod + "%' ", cx.StringConexao);
    da.Fill(tabela);

    double testeqtde = 0;
    double estoqueqtde = 0;
    double testetotal = 0;

    testeqtde = Convert.ToDouble(txtQtde.Text);
    estoqueqtde = Convert.ToDouble(tabela.Rows[0]);

    testetotal = estoqueqtde - testeqtde;
    if (testetotal < 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Não há quantidade o bastante no estoque! Quantidade:" + estoqueqtde);
    }
    else
    {
        if ((txtProCod.Text != "") && (txtQtde.Text != "") && (txtValor.Text != ""))
        {
            Double TotalLocal = Convert.ToDouble(txtQtde.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(txtValor.Text);//metodo para calcular o total do produto
            this.totalVenda = this.totalVenda + TotalLocal;//metodo para somar o total da compra
            String[] i = new String[] { txtProCod.Text, lProduto.Text, txtQtde.Text, txtValor.Text, TotalLocal.ToString() };//criado vetor de string
            this.dgvItens.Rows.Add(i);//adicionando o string dentro da datagrid

            txtProCod.Clear();//limpar o campo
            lProduto.Text = "Informe o código do produto ou clique em localizar";
            txtQtde.Clear();//limpar o campo
            txtValor.Clear();//limpar o campo

            txtTotalVenda.Text = this.totalVenda.ToString();//atualizar o total da compra

        }
    }
}
```

O problema realmente está ali no estoqueqtde,eu não sei que comando usar para pegar o unico valor que tem dentro da tabela que é o pro_qtde do produto que está sendo solicitado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem que dar uma melhorada nesse teu código, se você tem o código do produto, não tem necessidade usar like, e deixa o comando muito mais lento, vc pode não sentir com uma base de testes pequena, mas quando crescer, vai complicar. Outra coisa é concatenar variável como valor na cláusula where, isso pode adicionar fragilidade de segurança, o correto é usar a query com parâmetros. 
Dê uma olhada nessas dicas que vão lhe ajudar.

Quanto ao seu problema, altere o código como a seguir:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cx.StringConexao);
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Select pro_qtde from produto where pro_cod like '%" + cod + "%' ", conn);            
estoqueqtde = Convert.ToDouble(sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar());
```

Esse comando busca apenas um valor do banco e não uma coleção como é o caso do datatable.

Comment: Tem toda razão,isso resolve,muito obrigado pela ajuda Batista, vou tentar melhorar o código também,mesmo sendo uma base de teste pequena é sempre ideal adquirir bons hábitos de programação como esse

Answer (score 2):

Esse link vai responder a sua pergunta.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Realizar-select-e-exibir-8d90084c

Já adianto a você o código de exemplo que demonstra como fazer:

```
    public Form1() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
    } 

    //classe cliente e suas propriedades 
    public class Cliente 
    { 
        public int IdCliente { get; set; } 
        public string Nome { get; set; } 
        public string Email { get; set; } 
        public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; } 
    } 

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        CarregaListBox(); 
    } 

    private void CarregaListBox() 
    { 
        //instância da conexão 
        SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Clientes.sdf"); 

        //string com o comando a ser executado 
        string sql = "SELECT Nome from Cliente"; 

        //instância do comando recebendo como parâmetro 
        //a string com o comando e a conexão 
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, conn); 

        //abro conexão 
        conn.Open(); 

        //instância do leitor 
        SqlCeDataReader leitor = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 

        //enquanto leitor lê 
        while (leitor.Read()) 
        { 
            //para cada iteração adiciono o nome 
            //ao listbox 
            listBox1.Items.Add(leitor["Nome"].ToString()); 
        } 

        //fecha conexão 
        conn.Close(); 
    } 


    //método que faz a consulta no bd e obtém o cliente 
    //cujo o nome é informado pelo parâmetro 
    private Cliente ObterClientePorNome(string nome) 
    { 
        //objeto cliente que será retornado pelo método 
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente(); 

        //instância da conexão 
        SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Clientes.sdf"); 

        //string com o comando a ser executado 
        string sql = "SELECT * from Cliente WHERE Nome=@Nome"; 

        //instância do comando recebendo como parâmetro 
        //a string com o comando e a conexão 
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, conn); 

        //informo o parâmetro do comando 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", nome); 

        //abro conexão 
        conn.Open(); 

        //instância do leitor 
        SqlCeDataReader leitor = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 

        //enquanto leitor lê 
        while (leitor.Read()) 
        { 
            //passo os valores para o objeto cliente 
            //que será retornado 
            cliente.IdCliente = Convert.ToInt32(leitor["IdCliente"].ToString()); 
            cliente.Nome = leitor["Nome"].ToString(); 
            cliente.Email = leitor["Email"].ToString(); 
            cliente.DataNascimento = Convert.ToDateTime(leitor["DataNascimento"].ToString()); 
        } 

        //fecha conexão 
        conn.Close(); 

        //Retorno o objeto cliente cujo o  
        //nome é igual ao informado no parâmetro 
        return cliente; 
    } 

    //evento mouseclick do listbox 
    private void listBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
    { 
        //variável recebe o objeto cliente retornado pelo método 
        Cliente cliente = ObterClientePorNome(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()); 

        //passo os valores para os textbox 
        txtCodigo.Text = cliente.IdCliente.ToString(); 
        txtNome.Text = cliente.Nome; 
        txtEmail.Text = cliente.Email; 
        txtDataNascimento.Text = cliente.DataNascimento.ToShortDateString(); 
    }
```